# JetPack Navigation navigate to parent graph from child module

Tags: android, navigation, parent-child, android-jetpack-navigation

I’ve been playing around with JetPack’s Navigation Component. For the most part it’s pretty decent, although I’ve run into a few problems/cases for which I’ve not yet found a decent solution.

Let’s say we have a **Single Activity** app with **Modular Architecture** (packaging strategy?), and we don’t want to have a **God** module for navigation. We want all our modules to have their own `nav_graph` and we want to be able to jump back and forth from graph to graph.

Let’s say we have a dependency like this:
`app` --dependsOn--> `library` --dependsOn--> `details`. Both of `library` and `details` have their own `nav_graphs` which know about how to navigate in each of those modules.

Now if we’re in the `app` module, we would be able to directly navigate to any one of `details`’ destinations, since `app` knows about both `library` and `details`. But how do we navigate from `details` to, for instance, another one of `library`’s destinations?

One of the solutions I’ve found is via a `Router` of some sorts (usually an `Interface` inside a `God` module), which is not ideal, especially if you’re using something like `SafeArgs` because if you want to, for example, change a parameter you’re passing, you’d need to change the router’s method signatures etc.

The other solution I’ve found is to [add destinations dynamically](https://adevait.com/android/using-navigation-component-to-navigate-between-dynamic-feature-modules).
I’ve not actually been able to make this work for my case, although I remember reading somewhere that if you know the fully qualified name of the class/destination you should be able to navigate to it, despite Android Studio’s warnings.

Third thing I tried was using `popUpTo` with `inclusive=true` in the `nav_graph` definitions to kind of pop out of this graph, but I’ve had no luck with that (I was using a `NavDrawer` and wanted to pop back up to a top level location).

Has anyone found a good solution to this?

Comment: Did you find a solution, I am wondering the same...

Comment: Well there is some sort of a solution being devised for release `2.3.0` of the navigation library but it's still in alpha. Here's a link where you can read a bit more about it:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-dynamic#included